# Map X and Y coordinates are different than computed x and y coordinates?

Tags: qgis, coordinates, xy

I have some address points that I have reprojected to coordinate system EPSG 6626. Then, I added x and y coordinate attribute values using the "Add X/Y fields to layer" processing tool and have a table that looks like the table below. You can see the X values are in the 1510000's and y values are in the 7411000's.

[image]

When I look at the x and y locations of these address points in the map, they are showing accurate X values (1512558 for example) but the Y values are way off. The map screenshot below shows an X/Y coordinate of (1512558, 3402455) near the highlighted address point. I have set the project's coordinate projection to match the projection I used for the address layer - EPSG 6626.

Why are the Y values so far off in the map? Should the region not show the same range of values that were computed by the X/Y fields to layer plugin?

As an aside, I am trying to do network analysis and tie these address points to a network. It seems unable to locate these points along the tree perhaps due to their X, Y coordinates being off?

[image]

**UPDATE**

Here are the address coordinates in the original EPSG: 4326 projection. When I revert back to this original projection, and change the project coordinate projection back to EPSG: 4326, it is no longer an issue. I do need to have the units in US Feet so I will need to use a projection.

[image]

Comment: Please post Coordinates in their original Coordinate System. (Text please, not a photo.) I plugged in the top 2 Coordinates and they land somewhere in farm country. If you're looking for a residential subdivision, then EPSG:6626 is not the right Coordinate System.

Comment: @pointdump Thanks for looking into that. I've posted the original coordinates without reprojecting. The original data is in EPSG: 4326. The addresses are in Salt Lake City, Utah which EPSG: 6626 should cover. https://epsg.io/6626  Even if I used a wrong projection, reprojecting the coordinates using the wrong projection and then setting the project coordinate projection to that same incorrect projection should give me the same incorrect locations, no?

Comment: @pointdump looks like changing it to EPSG:6625 fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

Using the projection EPSG:6625 instead of EPSG:6626 solved the issue.